# POST API Request 500 internal error, The instance of entity cannot be tracked another instance is already being tracked. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

### The task:

Your task is to learn the ins and outs of potion brewing by handling **POST** requests at the **/potions** endpoint. The request consists of a **Potion** just brewed, containing the **Student ID**, and the **list of ingredients**. If a **Recipe** with these **Ingredients** **(in any order)** already exists, the **Potion** is a **replica**. If no such **Recipe** exists, the potion is a **discovery**, so the **Recipe** must also be persisted.

1. There is an endpoint at **/potions**, where a **Student** can brew the **Potion** by sending a **POST request**
2. The list of **Ingredients** is checked if it matches any **Potion**.
3. If the brew is a **discovery**, the **Recipe** is persisted with the **list of Ingredients**, the **Student**, and with a name generated from the **Student's name** *(e.g. "John Doe's discovery #2")*.
4. The response contains the persisted **Potion**.

---

##### Testing Replica status -> Add New Potion

The body consists of Ingredients are in the database already.
When I send a **POST** **REQUEST** to *{{ host_url }}/potions* with a raw-JSON body of :

```
{ 
    "brewer": 
        { 
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "Hermione Granger" 
        }
    "ingredients": 
        [ 
            { "name": "Mandrake" }, 
            { "name": "UnicordnBlood" }, 
            { "name": "UnicordnHair" }, 
            { "name": "Bezoar" }, 
            { "name": "Dittany" } 
        ] 
}
```

##### 500 Internal Server Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Ingredient' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at HogwartsPotions.Data.Services.PotionService.AddPotion(Potion newPotion) in ~\Data\Services\PotionService.cs:line 37
   at HogwartsPotions.Controllers.PotionController.AddPotion(Potion potion) in ~\Controllers\PotionController.cs:line 33
   at lambda_method19(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

##### Testing Discovery status -> Add New Potion

On the other hand, if the POST body request contains **"new"(not in the database yet)** Ingredients. It adds to the database and creates the Potion. **So the response is 201**

---

###### Controller :

```
namespace HogwartsPotions.Controllers
{
    [ApiController, Route("/potions")]
    public class PotionController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IPotionService _service;
        public PotionController(IPotionService context)
        {
            _service = context;
        }
 
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddPotion([FromBody] Potion potion)
        {
            var createdPotion = await _service.AddPotion(potion);
            if (createdPotion is null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            return Created("New Potion Added", potion);
        }
    }
}
```

###### PotionService:

```
namespace HogwartsPotions.Data.Services
{
    public class PotionService : IPotionService
    {
        private readonly HogwartsContext _context;
        public const int MaxIngredientsForPotions = 5;
 
        public PotionService(HogwartsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<List<Potion>> GetAllPotions()
        {
            return await _context.Potions
                .Include(p => p.Brewer)
                .Include(p => p.Ingredients)
                .Include(p => p.Recipe)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
 
        public async Task<Potion> AddPotion(Potion newPotion)
        {
            newPotion.Brewer = await _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(student => student.Id == newPotion.Brewer.Id);
            newPotion.Ingredients = SetPotionIngredients(newPotion);
            newPotion.Name = CreatePotionNameByBrewer(newPotion);
            newPotion.Status = SetBrewingStatus(newPotion);
            newPotion.Recipe = SetRecipeByBrewingStatus(newPotion);
 
            var potion = _context.Potions.Add(newPotion).Entity;
            //_context.Entry(newPotion).State = EntityState.Added;
            //_context.Entry<Potion>(newPotion).State = EntityState.Detached;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return potion;
        }
 
        private HashSet<Ingredient> SetPotionIngredients(Potion newPotion)
        {
            var storedIngredients = _context.Ingredients.AsNoTracking();
            var ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
            foreach (var newPotionIngredient in newPotion.Ingredients)
            {
                var currentIngredient = storedIngredients.FirstOrDefault(ingredient => ingredient.Name == newPotionIngredient.Name);
                ingredients.Add(currentIngredient ?? newPotionIngredient);
            }
            return ingredients;
        }
 
        private string CreatePotionNameByBrewer(Potion newPotion)
        {
            return $"{newPotion.Brewer.Name}'s Potion";
        }
 
        private Recipe SetRecipeByBrewingStatus(Potion newPotion)
        {
            if (newPotion.Status == BrewingStatus.Replica)
            {
                return newPotion.Recipe = GetRecipeByIngredients(newPotion.Ingredients);
            }
            return AddRecipeToPotion(newPotion);
        }
 
        private Recipe AddRecipeToPotion(Potion newPotion)
        { 
            return newPotion.Recipe = new Recipe()
            {
                Author = newPotion.Brewer,
                Name = CreateDiscoveryName(newPotion.Brewer.Name),
                Ingredients = newPotion.Ingredients,
            };
        }
 
        private string CreateDiscoveryName(string brewer)
        {
            int discoveryCount = _context.Recipes.Count(recipe => recipe.Author.Name == brewer);
            return $"{brewer}'s discovery {discoveryCount}#";
        }
 
        private Recipe GetRecipeByIngredients(HashSet<Ingredient> newPotionIngredients)
        {
            return _context.Recipes
                .Include(recipe => recipe.Ingredients)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .FirstOrDefault(recipe => recipe.Ingredients
                    .Select(ingredient => ingredient.Name)
                    .OrderBy(name => name)
                    .SequenceEqual(newPotionIngredients
                        .Select(ingredient => ingredient.Name)
                        .OrderBy(name => name)));
        }
 
        private BrewingStatus SetBrewingStatus(Potion newPotion)
        {
            if (IsIngredientsMatch(newPotion.Ingredients))
            {
                return BrewingStatus.Replica;
            }
            return BrewingStatus.Discovery;
        }
 
        private bool IsIngredientsMatch(HashSet<Ingredient> newPotionIngredients)
        {
            return _context.Recipes
                .Include(recipe => recipe.Ingredients)
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Any(recipe => recipe.Ingredients
                    .Select(ingredient => ingredient.Name)
                    .OrderBy(name => name)
                    .SequenceEqual(newPotionIngredients
                        .Select(ingredient => ingredient.Name)
                        .OrderBy(name => name)));
        }
    }
}
```

###### Entities

```
public class Ingredient
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Potion> Potions { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
 
}

public class Potion
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public Student Brewer { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
        public BrewingStatus Status { get; set; }
 
        public Potion()
        {
            Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
            Status = BrewingStatus.Brew;
        }
    }

public class Recipe
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Student Author { get; set; }
        public HashSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    }
```

[Database Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfgAl.png)

---

I have another question just because of curiosity.
So I approached comparing the two lists *(Potion ingredients <-> Recipe ingredients)* with .Except() but it throws **Object reference null** at the marked point. Any ideas how recipe.Ingredients can be null at this point ? :O

```
private bool IsIngredientsMatch(HashSet<Ingredient> newPotionIngredients)
        {
            List<string> PotionIngredients = new List<string>();
            foreach (var ingredient in newPotionIngredients)
            {
                PotionIngredients.Add(ingredient.Name);
            }
 
            var Recipes = _context.Recipes;
            foreach (var recipe in Recipes)
            {
                List<string> RecipeIngredients = new List<string>();
                foreach (var ingredient in recipe.Ingredients) // Object reference null
                {
                    RecipeIngredients.Add(ingredient.Name);
                }
                bool isEqual = !RecipeIngredients.Except(PotionIngredients).Any();
                if (isEqual)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I tried to collect all necessary information. If there is something missing or structurally incorrect. Please let me know ! 
**Constructive feedback always welcome**

I tried to change entity's state :

```
context.Entry(newPotion).State = EntityState.Added;
_context.Entry<Potion>(newPotion).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

and the Service from Scoped to Transient :

```
services.AddTransient<IPotionService, PotionService>();
```

Comment: Is "Unicordn" your intended spelling of Unicorn?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `AsNoTracking` method in `GetAllPotions` method:

```
public async Task<List<Potion>> GetAllPotions()
{
    return await _context.Potions
        .Include(p => p.Brewer)
        .Include(p => p.Ingredients)
        .Include(p => p.Recipe)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: You are right, I forgot .AsNoTracking(). Thanks for pointing out.
Maybe this time I provided to much information :D GetAllPotions method nothing to do with AddPotion.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please accept it (green check mark on the left).

Comment: Sure, I just need more reputation to cast a vote.

Comment: @Erik i was speaking about accepting answer, not upvoting

Comment: There is no connection between GetAllPotions and AddPotion. Therefore no, the issue didn't get fixed. Btw I have an idea where the problem lays. I'll try it tomorrow and update the post if its gonna work.